# Reading files,Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why output is different. The point of it is the same. Why specifying the amount of data through variable gives me such result?
Thanks for attention.

```
with open('/Users/tt/Desktop/words.py', 'r') as readings:
readings.read(10)
print(readings)

'I do know!'
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/tt/Desktop/words.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

with open('/Users/tt/Desktop/words.py', 'r') as readings:
tensymbols = readings.read(10)
print(tensymbols)

I do know!
```

Comment: Your IDE prints the stuff you get from `redings.read(10)` - then you print the filehandle which gives you `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/tt/Desktop/words.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`. Storing the return of the read(10) and printing the variable gives you _just_ what you read from it.

Comment: Please [edit] your code so the code doesn't have syntax errors. On the desktop verseion of the site, you can replace tae code you tried to post with a copy/paste of your actual working code; then select the pasted hode and type ctrl-K to format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to post your actual shell session so we can visualize what is going on. If this were simply run as a python script, we'd never see the first "I do know!" because it would have simply been discarded because it was not assigned to a variable.

In your first case, you read and discard the first 10 characters of the file. It turns out that the python shell and most IDE's will display the results of a function call if it isn't `None`, and that's what you see on the screen.

```
>>> with open('words.py') as readings:
...     readings.read(10)
... 
'I do know!'
>>> print(readings)
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='words.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Since you didn't assign the result of `readings.read(10)`, it is discarded… except the shell showed it to you first.

In your second case, you keep the returned string and can use it later.

```
>>> with open('words.py') as readings:
...     tensymbols = readings.read(10)
... 
>>> print(tensymbols)
I do know!
>>> print(readings)
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='words.py' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>>
```

Notice that if you print `readings` like the fist time, its an io wrapper just like the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are a'parently running this from Python's REPL (the `>>>` interactive prompt).

The first attempt returns the string you read as a Python string (with quotes). Then you ask Python to `print` the open file handle, and because thereeis no sensible string representation for a file handle, P
Ython prints its `repr()` string.

The second attempt simply asks Python to `print` the string; because this is a string which doesn't have to be mangled to produce a human-readable representation, it's printed verbatim.